# pagemessages not working with page reference

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I have 2 vf and 2 controllers
 pages message and download button is there in my search vf page
n controller code is here

**VF**

```
<apex:page standardController="Detail__c" extensions="MazeChangesSearchController" title="maze Changes Search" docType="html-5.0" readOnly="true"><apex:form id="form">

    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="headerStyle"> 
    <apex:pageBlock id="pageBlock" title="maze Changes Search">
           <apex:outputPanel id="pageMessagePanel">

                    <apex:pageMessages id="pageMessage" />
          </apex:outputPanel>
      <div class="row" align="center"> 
            <apex:outputpanel id="mazeChangesButton">
                 <apex:commandButton action="{!dummy}" onclick="setHiddenmaze();" rerender="false"  value="Download" status="loadStatus" id="download"></apex:commandButton>
            </apex:outputpanel>
        </div>
        <br/>
           <apex:actionFunction name="mazechangesFunction" action="{!mazechanges}" rerender="pageMessage"></apex:actionFunction>
                </apex:pageBlock >

    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form><script type="text/javascript">

    function setHiddenmaze({mazechangesFunction();
    }
 }
</script>
</apex:page>
```

---

**Contoller**

```
 public PageReference mazechanges(){
       PageReference pageRef;
       List<maze__c> mazecount=[Select id from maze__c];

       if(mazecount.size()==0){

          ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'Cannot download file since there are no maze changes for the selected date range')); 
       }
       else{
          //ApexPages.getMessages().clear();
          system.debug('employerName='+empname);
          system.debug('mazeMonthFrom='+mazeMonthFrom);
          system.debug('mazeMonthTo='+mazeMonthTo);
          pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/DownloademazeChanges');
          pageRef.setRedirect(true);
          pageRef.getParameters().put('employerName','empname');
          pageRef.getParameters().put('mazeMonthFrom',mazeMonthFrom);
          pageRef.getParameters().put('mazeMonthTo',mazeMonthTo);

          system.debug('pageRef='+pageRef);
       }
       return pageRef;
}
```

whene i try to search and list count is zero page message is getting displayed correctly but if i try to search again with proper data file is getting downloaded but message is not getting cleared.

Comment: Try adding `ApexPages.getMessages().clear();` in the else part.

Comment: i had tried that but message din't get chanage as u can can see the commented part

Comment: If I remove page reference part it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4):

Replace `rerender="false"` with `rerender="pageMessagePanel"` in `apex:commandButton`